# Parse a string with a key and value to an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

[Edited because my question was not clear]

I would like to parse each string from an array into an object as its key with an assigned value e.x.:

There is an array called dates.

This is dates[0]

`"2022-02-01"`

And I would like to parse it in an object that looks like this:

```
let datesObj = { "2022-02-01": {selected: true, marked: true} }
```

I have looked into JSON.parse() but I have not been able to apply it to my needs in this case (if that is even the solution).

I haven't been able to find a suitable solution, so a big thank you to anyone willing to help.

Comment: you mean use the string as a key in an object?

Comment: It seems like you don't really want to parse the string, but to just build on object having the string as key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```js
function parse(date)
{
    const res = {}
    res[date] = {
        selected: true, 
        marked: true
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: @DanielCMGT. The function should rather be called something like `build_date_object` instead of `parse`. It isn't really parsing the date.

Comment: The problem here was that one couldn't just write `let datesObj = { date: { ... } }` because that would make `datesObj` have the key `date` instead of for example `2022-02-01`.

Comment: That is true. I ran into that problem which made me second guess the use of .parse(). But I was not able to find an alternative which is why the question was raised. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

wrap your string with breakets

```
var mystring='{"2022-02-01": {selected: true, marked: true}}';
```

and then try parsing it with

```
var myobj=JSON.parse(mystring);
```

Comment: The reason this works is the outer brackets makes it an object with string keys and string values, thus enabling `.parse()` to be used.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. However, I realised I did not properly phrase my question. I have edited since. Could you take a look at it again?